# Couple columns from result into one separated with comma

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I got this query

```
declare var1 nvarchar(100)
    set @var1='84,85,86'
    SET @sql = N'select a1 from DamDocumentType1 where documentid in (' + @var1 + ')' ;
    EXEC (@SQL);
```

The result i get comes in one column and 4 rows. For example:

3/2014

4/2014

5/2014

8/2014

How can i put this couple of rows in one row and one column and separate them with comma.For example:

3/2014,4/2014,5/2014,8/2014

I use that query for something so now i need it fixed to do this thing i just explained, i cant figure it out. You can say that I'm new in this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this,

```
DECLARE @var1 NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max) = ''

SET @var1 = '84,85,86'
SET @SQL = 'select stuff((
            SELECT '', '' + a1
            FROM DamDocumentType1
            where documentid in (' + @var1 + ')
            FOR XML path('''')
            ), 1, 2, '''')'

EXEC(@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
SET @sql = N'select STUFF((select '','' + cast(a1 as VARCHAR(10)) from DamDocumentType1 where documentid in (' + @var1 + ') FOR XML PATH('''')),1,1,'''') AS a1' ;
```